# Strange error when downloading react-native project as well as when running an existing project

Tags: react-native, npm

An error like this when I was downloading the new project occurred, and when I was running an existing project in `react-native` this error also came:

> npm WARN deprecated deep-assign@3.0.0: Check out `lodash.merge` or
>   `merge-options` instead. npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7:
>   core-js@<2.6.8 is no longer maintained. Please, upgrade to core-js@3
>   or at least to actual version of core-js@2. npm ERR!
>   error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\Lasitha\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-10-01T15_12_03_834Z-debug.log
>   npm exited with non-zero code: 1 Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to
>   view the stack trace.

Comment: Could you update the question with the log output referenced in the error?